# How to make a row of a datagrid bold if that rows item is true?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So let say I have a custom class:

```
Class Elements{

    int width;
    int height;
    bool isBol;

}
```

and in main I have something like:

```
Public class MainWindow{

    DataGrid dgv = new DataGrid();
    List<Elements> elem = new List<Elements() { 
         new Element(){width=100, height = 200, isBold = false}, 
         new Element(){ width=20, height=100, isBold = true}
    };

    dgv.ItemsSource = elem;

    dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { 
           Header = "Width", Binding = new Binding("width")}
    dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { 
           Header = "Height", Binding = new Binding("height")}

}
```

So it is just a simple table with 2 columns, width and height.

How would I make a row appear to be bold based on the bool value isBold? In my example above, the row 20x100 should appear to be bold in the table, where 100x200 should NOT be bold.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use a `DataTrigger` in an Implicit `Style`

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isBold}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: can't seem to get this to work... (I did add <Style.Triggers></Style.Triggers> around the DataTrigger)

Comment: @Toadums Does your `Elements` class use properties or fields for the `isBold` property, and is it public? It won't work with the code you have in your question. You'll need `public bool IsBold { get; set; }` for it to work.

Comment: I'm not using that exact code. But isBool is public, and...I am not sure if it is a property or field...I believe it is a field, I just go public bool isBold = false; when I declare it.

Comment: @Toadums Switch it to `public bool isBold { get; set; }` and see if that corrects the issue. I believe the dependency property system doesn't work with fields, and you need to switch it to a property with a `get` and `set` accessor

Comment: any Idea how to make it work if I only want the first cell to be bolded?

Comment: @LouisRhys You should post a new question with a sample of your code. You probably only need to apply the style to the first `<DataGridColumn>` in your `<DataGrid.Columns>`, but it depends on how your code looks